# Spring MVC Request Mapping passes requests that should not be passed

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, http-status-codes

**EDIT** - This is now solved, the error was in my spring configuration. I had missed the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` tag. When adding it, everything worked as expected.

I have defined a controller using Spring MVC that should accept`HTTP GET` requests to the address `/controllertest` only if the content type of the request is `application/json`. It also returns data in `application/json`and therefore only requests that accept data in that format should pass. However, this does not work.

This is my code using Spring 3.2.0:

```
package test.controllers;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controllertest")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String helloJSON() {
        return "{\"message\":\"HelloWorld\"}";  
    }

}
```

This is what I expect:

1. If I use any HTTP method other than `GET` I should receive a `405 - Method not allowed` response
2. If I send a request that do not accept `application/json` I should receive a `406 Not Acceptable` response.
3. If I send a request with a Content-Type other than `application/json` I should receive a `415 Unsupported Media Type` response.

This is the actual result:

1. I do actually get a `405 - Method not allowed`. Very nice.
2. When sending a request with an `Accept` header with `text/xml` only I get a `200 - OK` response and the content type of the response is `text/xml` even though the method only produces `application/json`.
3. When sending a request where the content type is `text/xml` I get a `200 - OK` response.

I may add that I implemented all of this in Jersey and the results were all correct.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring 3.2 the behavior is along the lines of what you have described, except for 2 where I got a 405(method not allowed) instead of 406. Can you confirm which version of Spring are you using for these tests and if it feasible to upgrade to atleast 3.10+ and confirm once more this behavior.

Comment: I do indeed use spring 3.2.0.RELEASE (from maven repository). Sorry for not including this in my question.

Comment: Do you get a 405 when you use the correct HTTP method but use an Accept header that does not include the content type specified in "produces"?

Comment: Yes, not able to explain the behavior you are seeing though